Build Failure in atlas-mvn clean package: "Error unpacking file" due to case-sensitive paths
I am new to Java programming and trying to build my application using the Atlassian Maven Plugin with the following command:
atlas-mvn   clean  package

However, I encounter this error during the process:
[INFO] --- confluence:9.1.1:copy-bundled-dependencies (default-copy-bundled-dependencies) @ GStorage ---
[WARNING] Archive entry 'META-INF/license/' and existing file '/Users/dsingh/Documents/github/CONFLUENCE/GStorage/target/classes/META-INF/LICENSE' names differ only by case. This may lead to an unexpected outcome on case-insensitive filesystems.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.546 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-11-21T07:17:00Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:confluence-maven-plugin:9.1.1:copy-bundled-dependencies (default-copy-bundled-dependencies) on project GStorage: Error unpacking file: /Users/dsingh/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.67.1/grpc-netty-shaded-1.67.1.jar to: /Users/dsingh/Documents/github/CONFLUENCE/GStorage/target/classes: Error while expanding /Users/dsingh/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.67.1/grpc-netty-shaded-1.67.1.jar: /Users/dsingh/Documents/github/CONFLUENCE/GStorage/target/classes/META-INF/LICENSE/LICENSE.aix-netbsd.txt: Not a directory -> [Help 1]

I attempted to exclude the problematic paths in the pom.xml file by adding the following configuration:in pom.xml
  <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>confluence-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/license/*</exclude>
                  </excludes>

the error still persists. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
